# PowerShell not returning items in current directory with wildcard

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script to automatically create and upload Nuget packages to a local Nuget feed, but I'm having some issues with PowerShell that I don't understand.

The first step is to create all the packackages with this command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Include *.nuspec -Recurse | Foreach {nuget pack $_.fullname}
```

This goes in to each project directory and recursively looks for .nuspec files, and builds the .nupkg file for each of them, placing it in the solution directory. In this case "MultiPack.Client.1.0.0.nupkg", "MultiPack.Common.1.0.0.nupkg", and "MultiPack.Server.1.0.0.nupkg". It seems to be working just fine.

[image: Directory listing]

The next step would be to run `nuget add fileName.nupkg -Source "c:\localNuget"` on each of those files. I modified the previous command to:

```
Get-ChildItem -Include *.nupkg | Foreach {nuget add $_.fullname -Source c:\localNuget}
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.  Doing some debugging, I find that `Get-ChildItem -Include *.nupkg` produces no results even though the files are definitely there.  It works if I use `-Recurse`, but I don't really want to do that, since the .nupkg files will always be in the current directory.

Why isn't it finding my files with the wildcard, and how can I change the script to work without the `-Recurse` flag?

Comment: Try `-Filter` instead of `-Include`

Comment: That works, Thank you!  Can you explain why though?  I'm reading the documentation on the `-Filter` and `-Include` options, but the difference isn't very clear, they *both* sound like they should do what I want.  The example for `Include` even explicitly shows using "*.txt".

Comment: I never use `-Include` because I have no idea what the difference to `-Filter` is, exactly. And what `-Filter` does is abundantly clear and typically exactly what I want. So... no, I can't really explain why. :)

Comment: The [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) this: *"The `-Include` parameter is effective only when the command includes the `-Recurse` parameter or the path leads to the contents of a directory, such as `C:\Windows*`, where the `"*"` wildcard character specifies the contents of the `C:\Windows` directory."* but to be absolutely honest, that doesn't really help my understanding.

Comment: I jsut found this [blog post](https://tfl09.blogspot.com/2012/02/get-childitem-and-theinclude-and-filter.html) gives a pretty good explanation on what is going on.  I've come to the conclusion that PowerShell just has some strange quirks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `-Include` has a perfectly logical explanation (I reckon it's something along the lines of what paths to include in the recursion) and its ability to filter files is a mere byproduct of its *actual* purpose. So using it just to filter files would be using it against its design and quirks are to be expected. Unfortunately, MS did a poor job at explaining its function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Tomalak

> Try -Filter instead of -Include

Reason:

You need a "-Recurse" to get this working with Include

> The -Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the
>   -Recurse parameter or the path leads to the contents of a directory, such as C:\Windows*, where the "*" wildcard character specifies the
>   contents of the C:\Windows directory.